# What's the Ruby equivalent of Python's defaultdict?

Tags: python, ruby, dictionary, language-comparisons, autovivification

In Python, I can make a hash where each element has a default value when it's first referenced (also know as "autovivification"). Here's an example:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(int)
d["new_key"] += 1
print d
```

Printing the dict shows the value for "new_key" is 1.

What's the equivalent in Ruby? This code throws an error:

```
d = {}
d[:new_key] += 1
puts d

test.rb:3:in `<main>': undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use the first argument of the [`Hash.new`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Hash.html#method-c-new) method for that:

```
d = Hash.new 0
d[:new_key] += 1
d[:new_key] #=> 1
d[:foo]     #=> 0
```

Be careful - you might accidentally change the default value:

```
h = Hash.new("Go Fish")
h[:unknown_key]         #=> "Go Fish"
h[:unknown_key].upcase! #=> "GO FISH"
h[:next_key]            #=> "GO FISH"
```

As "mu is too short" pointed out in his answer, you should better use a proc, as in:

```
h = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = 0 }
```

Comment: How do you create a hash with both a default value and keys `:unknown_key` and `:next_key`?

Answer (score 29):

You can assign a default value using [`default=`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-default-3D):

```
d.default = 0
```

Note that this won't really autovivify though, it just makes `d[:new_key]` return a zero without actually adding a `:new_key` key. `default=` can also cause problems if you intend to modify the default value; that means that `d.default = [ ]` is almost always a mistake as the array will not be copied when the default is accessed.

A better choice is usually [`default_proc=`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-default_proc-3D):

```
d.default_proc = proc { |h, k| h[k] = 0 }
```

This allows you to have distinct default values and it allows you to add the new key (or not depending on how the `proc` is structured).

You can also set these when creating the Hash:

```
d = Hash.new(0)
d = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = 0 }
```

Comment: I agree. I cannot delete my answer, so I'll add a note to it.

Answer (score 10):

The standard `new` method for Hash accepts a block. This block is called in the event of trying to access a key in the Hash which does not exist. The block is passed the Hash itself and the key that was requested (the two parameters) and should return the value that should be returned for the requested key.

This can be used to create an autovivified hash, among other things:

```
h = Hash.new{ |h,k| h[k] = 'default value'}
```